# After hard drive updated to SSD and memory upgrade Windows freezes and throw BSoD en less than 30 minutes, it works fine under Linux

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-installation

I have an Asus Vivobook X505ZA that had 8G on board and a 1TB standard hard drive.

**I decided to upgrade the hard drive to a 420 GB SSD and add 16GB (1 slot) for a total of 24GB of RAM**

That memory is a Samgsun of 2400Mhz that is being detected fine by the BIOS and memory diagnosis tools have label as "passed tests"

I had my Windows 10 Pro ISO that used to work before, so used that one, the installation goes well and fast, but **after using windows for a couple of minutes I get BSoD with one of these errors**

- clock-watchdog-timeout (most frequent one)
- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

**I have tried** installing Chipset drivers, and **updating all drivers** (including Radeon Vega 8 driver) and also using the AVG Driver Updater, and all processes finish fine, but the BSoD continues usually in less than 30 minutes.

I have also tried with **Windows updates, but they get stuck at 0% or 15% of download but always fail to install**. With the windows upgrade assistant It downloaded after 3 reboots and it installed after other 3 reboots and then Windwos EFI loader got corrupted

I have tried using other more recent builds of Windows ISO files but they dont even load the installation proccess, the same USB works on other Laptop, **In total I have made close to 10 Windows installations that all behave the same**

I have enabled/disable CSM support and disable secure boot.

**I have flashed my BIOS** to the most recent version 313 and also the previous one 312 with the same issues.

I know that Linux has a much smaller memory foot-print so that might be the reason that I'm not seeing the issues there (that and of course a more robust driver arquitecture)

The initial upgrade has done with a Crucial memory of 16GB of up to 2666 MHz but I changed that to the Samsung one and still the same issues.

**So What else can I try to Windows 10 work on this new configuration ?
what can be causing all this ?**

**UPDATE of WinDbg information of the BSoD**

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.685 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\050821-38437-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 10240 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 10240.16384.amd64fre.th1.150709-1700
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`d368b000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`d39aff30
Debug session time: Sat May  8 17:33:23.148 2021 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:10:22.875
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
..............................
Loading User Symbols
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (101)
An expected clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor in an
MP system within the allocated interval. This indicates that the specified
processor is hung and not processing interrupts.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000018, Clock interrupt time out interval in nominal clock ticks.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, 0.
Arg3: ffffd0009ec80180, The PRCB address of the hung processor.
Arg4: 0000000000000005, The index of the hung processor.

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 3

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on DESKTOP-E896S63

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 4

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 71

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject


BUGCHECK_CODE:  101

BUGCHECK_P1: 18

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd0009ec80180

BUGCHECK_P4: 5

FAULTING_PROCESSOR: 5

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff803`d530bc18 fffff803`d37f1801 : 00000000`00000101 00000000`00000018 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`9ec80180 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff803`d530bc20 fffff803`d3695826 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00005cd0 00000000`0000000c fffff803`d39ee180 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xb001
fffff803`d530bcb0 fffff803`d369622d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`000013d6 00000000`00005cd0 00000000`00000001 : nt!KiUpdateRunTime+0x56
fffff803`d530bd10 fffff803`d361caa6 : 00000124`5499068c 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`9f769340 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x53d
fffff803`d530bf40 fffff803`d375a327 : fffff803`d36662e0 fffff803`d3832c65 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x56
fffff803`d530bf70 fffff803`d37d8fea : fffff803`d36662e0 fffff803`d39ee180 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000002 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0x87
fffff803`d530bfb0 fffff803`d37d9417 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xea
ffffd000`9f769340 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+b001

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  b001

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_VRF_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

OS_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

BUILDLAB_STR:  th1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ee16f05f-246b-d0d7-9e9a-d626b64c0212}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

---

Comment: Do NOT enable CSM, disable it! If you have UEFI all your OSes should be installed in UEFI mode. Regarding Windows in this particular problem, reinstall it. There's really nothing else left to do.

Comment: Like I have said on my question I have installed Windows many times, from different ISOs, from USB, from external hardrive and with and without CSM enabled, is still the same problem

Comment: What if you just run Windows with one of the 2 RAMs. Either 8 GB or 16 GB but never both together? Do you have a stable system? I assume you are familiar with handling/inserting/removing Laptop RAM so that you can try this yourself.

Comment: If you have a dump file of IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL analyse that. Processor 5 is the sixth processor as it starts at 0.

Comment: that error has not happened any more, only the CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT is still happening. Also I have just detected that the BIOS clock is not keeping the time correctly, maybe a change of the CMOS battery is needed.

Comment: And is that a hardware error on the sixth processor or is there something that can be done ?

Comment: Start msconfig as admin. Boot tab, Advanced Options and set max CPU to 5. This assumes processor 6 is in each crash dump.

Comment: @user1292580 Thanks so much for all the information you have provided me. Yesterday after leaving the laptop battery drain completly the BIOS was unable to keep the date/time. So I will change that CMOS Battery and if needid I will limit the amount of cores as you explained. -- THANK SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME -- instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking the computer to a official ASUS support and paying to get a diagnosis of "yes sr,Windows is producing a blue screen of death"
combined with a "you have an issue with your mother board and (new) ssd drive"

I decided to give it another try.

It seems the issue was with all the ISO files that I tried, either because they got corrupted or because they where too old and did not handle the SSD correctly

So i created a ISO file using the Windows 10 Medial Tool creator
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Used rufus to crete a MBR/UEFI USB with Windows 10 21H1 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**Bug Check 0x101: CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT**

The `CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT` bug check has a value of `0x00000101`. This indicates that an expected clock interrupt on a secondary processor, in a multi-processor system, was not received within the allocated interval.

`CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT` Parameters

The following parameters are displayed on the blue screen.

**Parameter Description**

**1**
Clock interrupt time-out interval, in nominal clock ticks

**2**
0

**3**
The address of the processor control block (PRCB) for the unresponsive processor

**4**
0

Cause
The specified processor is not processing interrupts. Typically, this occurs when the processor is nonresponsive or is deadlocked.

From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x101---clock-watchdog-timeout

Your second error is here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xa--irql-not-less-or-equal. This is usually a driver error. **You can use Driver Verifier if the message doesn't have the driver's name- type `verifier` in Start - Run (Winkey+R) and follow the wizard.**

---

**Dump Files**

Dump files are files containing the state of the machine when it crashed. We can analyse the file to identify the driver (or program) causing the crash. See the last section on how to get them analysed by a volunteer.

**Analyse Dump Files**

If you want to analyse your own dump files.

You need to access the files in C:\windows\Minidump. Right click WinDbg and choose Run As Administrator.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called `Symbols` in `C:\`

Start `Windbg`. *File* menu - *Symbol File Path* and enter

`srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

Close and reopen `WinDbg`. *File* menu - *Open Crash Dump*

This will analyse the crash dump. You need to close and reopen `WinDbg` for each dump file analysed. Because you are downloading symbols from the internet `WinDbg` will appear to be doing nothing. But it's downloading. Be patient.

You are looking for a driver or system library that the crash occurred in at the end of the listing. Find the file, right click then *Properties - Details* tab. If it shows a driver you'll need to update the driver identified.

Comment: The description of the error is useful, but the provided link does not mention any solution or more details, under Linux not a single error related the processor is displayed

Comment: But my final sentence does as the second link suggests. Plus you could use a debugger to examine PRCB. Debugging Tools for Windows can be downloaded here from Microsoft - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/

Comment: I have just removed the added RAM and the problem continues, some of the windows updates where able to be installed but one of them corrupted the windows.efi file and now I have to re-install again. I will try that tool and let you know thanks

Comment: Thanks so much for your help I have updated the question with the results of the WinDbg and !analyze, it seems like processor(core) 5 did not process/received and interruption. Is there anything that can be done to address this issue ? -