# Having issues Installing TWRP Recovery On Huawei Mediapad T3 10 from Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb, android

I'm running Windows 10 and an Administrative command prompt for all commands.

I got to to Install TWRP Recovery On Huawei Mediapad T3 10 as mentioned in this document
https://www.droidguides.com/unlock-bootloader-install-twrp-recovery-huawei-mediapad-t3-10/

I have:

- Installed the USB driver
- Enabled Developer options && USB debbugging
- The USB transfer has been set to PTP

From the link above when I run this command, it works without issues (adb devices show the tablet connected)

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

After that command is run the tablet shows this window

[image]

When I type this command

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

it shows `waiting for device`, and if I run adb devices now the list of devices is empty

How can I solve this.

**UPDATE**

Someone has voted to close this question because does not follow the community guideline, but

- I did my research in at least 10 sites before posting here, the only link I shared is because is the only one relevant
- My question is on topic, since is about hardware/software support
- My question is very specific, has all the details
- It can help other people since many people is interesed in installing TWRP

As mention here - https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The web site clearly states that an unlocked bootloader is a requirement for installing twrp. Have you unlocked the bootloader? For fatboot have you installed fastboot drivers? Adb drivers don't work in bootloader mode.

Comment: The only good source for those drivers is the Android SDK provided by Google.

Comment: Having Android SDK installed does not automatically means fastboot driver is installed and properly assigned to the device. When device is in fastboot mode and connected via USB to the PC make sure the device manager does not show a device with yellow exclamation mark. You can also change view to Device by connection, open the device tree up to the used USB root hub and check if the fastboot device is present and uses the fastboot driver.

Comment: I would like to upvote your "answer currently in the form of comments" thanks - I will try that later (my kid is using the device right know) - I what I meant on my first comment was "does the steps mentioned in that article are what I need to do"

Comment: Please do not ask questions that require knowledge of off-site resources. Those sites may be gone tomorrow leaving a question that is of no use to other users. Therefore please always include the steps you are talking about into your question. Also check https://android.stackexchange.com there you will find plenty of posts about device rooting and adb/fastboot. What really makes me wonder is that Huawei devices are usually known for their bootloader that can't be unlocked as Huawei discontinued that years ago.

Comment: You mean that I should ask a question like this other one, with all the details that was viewed 140 times and only 1 answer and 1 downvote - https://superuser.com/questions/1647442/after-hard-drive-updated-to-ssd-and-memory-upgrade-windows-freezes-and-throw-bso do you expect my to copy the whole steps from a website with steps that I have not executed. There is a reason people talk bad about stackoverflow and this site, is because your kind of attitude. You should also provide your answer as answer and not like comments (specially if you like following rules) - check my SO profile if it helps

Comment: My question clearly mentions all the steps that I have done, and that information does not depend on anything external. What more details do you need ?

Comment: I a writing in comments because I can't answer your question on a smartphone in a way that satisfies my quality criteria for a good answer. Also I am still confused how you can follow a tutorial which has a requirement for an unlocked bootloader which you don't have and you don't know how to get.

Comment: @Robert have you ever skipped a step when reading instructions ? that is what happened, I have not still found the official link of the google Android Bootloader Interface Drivers, Also I thought the instructions where to "unlock the bootloader" is better to ask than to assume something about me - thanks for your guidance

Comment: Yes I am human, thus I also make mistakes. For example I did not directly recognize that the linked rooting tutorial is heavily outdated and therefore of no use to you. As I wrote Huawei devices can't be bootloader unlocked anymore which makes the whole rooting tutorial pointless. Therefore if you would manage to get fastboot to work the `fastboot flash ...` command would fail because of the locked bootloader. I am sorry but this is the end of the road. Your goal is not reachable no matter what you do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/can-we-consider-huawei-phones-as-unrootable)

Answer (score 1):

adb and fastboot are different modes with different protocols, different interfaces, different drivers and different programs. therefore `adb.exe` is not working while phone is connected in fastboot mode, and vice versa.

Windows driver signature enforcement should be disabled so that one can install unsigned drivers.

- Hold down shift while restarting Windows to enter advanced boot options
- in menu select - Troubleshoot - Advanced options - Startup Settings
- hit F7 for Disable driver signature enforcement

In Windows device manager select phone while connected in fastboot mode and install `android_winusb.inf`, select Android Bootloader Interface

Your phone now will be detected from `fastboot.exe`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb